How do I call emit() from a partial class(extension MyCubitExtension on MyCubit) whose parent class extends Cubit<MyState> in Flutter?
At first, I had my_cubit.dart file but it was getting too long so I decided to divide it.
Now I have two files: my_cubit.dart, my_cubit.extension.dart as below
my_cubit.dart:
part 'my_cubit.extension.dart';

class MyCubit extends Cubit<MyState> {...}

my_cubit.extension.dart:
part of 'my_cubit.dart';

extension MyCubitExtension on MyCubit {
    void getResult() {
        emit(GettingResult);
        ...
    }
}

However, this does not work as I wished. (I want what's inside MyCubitExtension to be treated the same as what's in MyCubit)
Warning:
The member 'emit' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:bloc/src/bloc_base.dart'.dart(invalid_use_of_protected_member)
The member 'emit' can only be used within 'package:bloc/src/bloc_base.dart' or a test.dartinvalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member
What can I do?
I kind of get that emit() method is protected so it cannot be used inside the extension. Then what's the alternative? The goal is to basically use the two files as if they were one single file?

@pskink no because even after I would need to break down the class MyCubit extends Cubit {...}

interestingly enough, I don't get an error when calling emit() inside my_cubit.extension.dart, just the warning. Not sure if I can just ignore the warning though.

you can try mixins?

Personally I have never tried this approach but one way can be:
mixin CubitActions on Cubit<MyState> {
  void getResult() {
    emit(GettingResult);
    ...
  }
}

class MyCubit extends Cubit<MyState> with CubitActions {...}

This way you can also access getResults()
or you can create a vanilla method in the Cubit that justs takes state and emits and access it in the extension
